# Stored procedure executed via task fails - Error mentions UDF instead of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call a stored procedure via a task, but keep on getting the error:

> SQL compilation error:
> Unknown user-defined function
> STAGING_SILVER.MARKETING.SP_UPDATE_MSCV_SOURCE

I have granted usage of database / schema where the task and stored procedure live to the role calling the procedure but still same error.

The stored procedure is long but here is the beginning:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STAGING_SILVER.MARKETING.SP_UPDATE_MSCV_SOURCE()
RETURNS NUMBER(38,0)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 'declare

  rows_inserted integer     default 0;
  rows_updated  integer     default 0;
  status        integer     default 0;  

begin.....
```

And the task calling the stored procedure is defined as :

```
create or replace task STAGING_SILVER.MARKETING.UPDATE_MSCV_SOURCE
    warehouse=STAGING_FT_WH
    schedule='using cron 0 0 30 2 1 Pacific/Auckland'
    as call STAGING_SILVER.MARKETING.SP_UPDATE_MSCV_SOURCE();
```

I am running out of things to try so posting the question here. I also find it weird that the error mentions a user defined function instead of a procedure... Any advice or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the stored procedure work when called directly, not using a task to call it?

Comment: yes, it does. No errors there

Comment: If you're using the newer Snowsight UI, in Activity > Query History you can pull down the filters and toggle on the option for `Queries executed by user tasks`. That should show you the SQL the task tried to run. Hopefully you can see if it has a compile error on it and why.

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately , there is no new information via this technique

Comment: You mentioned that you granted usage on db/schema where the task is created to the role who can call the SP.  Not sure if you checked, but worth trying, as it might the case if the "role" who runs the task does not have USAGE privileges on your stored procedure. In the case of TASK, the task ownership holder should have the usage on SP. You can run ```show grants on task <task name>```, to see the owner, and then ```grant usage on procedure <procedure name> to role <task owner role name>```. Could you please check and let us know if the task owner has usage on the SP?